# Can I specify scaling when using the cairosvg module inside of python

Tags: python, svg, png, cairo

The command line version of cairosvg allows scaling.  Here is the output of the help function:

```
cairosvg -h
usage: cairosvg [-h] [-v] [-f {pdf,png,ps,svg}] [-d DPI] [-W WIDTH]
            [-H HEIGHT] [-s SCALE] [-u] [-o OUTPUT]
            input

CairoSVG - A simple SVG converter based on Cairo.

positional arguments:
   input                 input filename or URL

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --version         show program\'s version number and exit
  -f {pdf,png,ps,svg}, --format {pdf,png,ps,svg}
                        output format
  -d DPI, --dpi DPI     ratio between 1 inch and 1 pixel
  -W WIDTH, --width WIDTH
                        width of the parent container in pixels
  -H HEIGHT, --height HEIGHT
                        height of the parent container in pixels
  -s SCALE, --scale SCALE
                        output scaling factor
```

see also [cairosvg documentation](http://cairosvg.org/documentation/)

How can one specify a scaling factor when using `cairosvg2png` inside of a Python script?

Comment: this is clever http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python but I am hoping for a native python solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this [commit](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/commit/1a0eba6d92a599546d042dd0cabeaebc7481b770#diff-8c7df791840f2be1eef6ab7d025177b8) 2 new parameters where added.

```py
[... other params]
output_width=None,
output_height=None
```

For me `output_height` and `output_width` did the job.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question - the documentation doesn't make this explicit, but as it turns out, it's as simple as passing the `scale=2.0` keyword argument to the `svg2png` method.

```
import cairosvg

input_fn = '/home/me/input.svg'
output_fn = '/home/me/output.png'

cairosvg.svg2png(url=input_fn, write_to=output_fn, scale=2.0)
```

This definitely works for me on version 2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

the documentation has been updated at:  http://cairosvg.org/documentation/ with [API documentation commit](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/commit/688ec56372fff64a777f55139bd8e64797ed69c8)